# Need to filter a column by time using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, time, filtering

I have a database of weather information that I need to filter by a range of years. I know how to do that. Then I need to filter by a certain time of day. From noon to six pm. So essentially I need to find every row that occurred from 2000 - 2005 and from 12pm to 6pm. I can't for the life of me figure out how to filter the time. The column is not date time. It is just time in the hh:mm:ss format.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

tor = pd.read_csv("1950-2019_actual_tornadoes.csv")

cond1 = tor['yr'] > 1999
cond2 = tor['yr'] < 2006
cond3 = tor['time'] >= 12:00:00
cond4 = tor['time'] <= 18:00:00

print(tor[cond1 & cond2 & cond3 & cond4])
```

The error code I get is that the colons in the time is invalid syntax. If I take the colons out, it tells me that the comparison operators are not supported between a string and an integer.

Example of dataframe:

| om | yr | mo | dy | date | time | tz | st | stf | stn | mag | inj | fat | loss | closs | slat | slon | elat | elon | len | wid | ns | sn | sg | f1 | f2 | f3 | f4 | fc |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1950 | 01 | 03 | 1950-01-03 | 11:00:00 | 3 | MO | 29 | 1 | 3 | 3 | 0 | 6.0 | 0.0 | 38.77 | -90.22 | 38.83 | -90.03 | 9.5 | 150 | 2 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | 1950 | 01 | 03 | 1950-01-03 | 11:55:00 | 3 | IL | 17 | 2 | 3 | 3 | 0 | 5.0 | 0.0 | 39.1 | -89.3 | 39.12 | -89.23 | 3.6 | 130 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 135 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 3 | 1950 | 01 | 03 | 1950-01-03 | 16:00:00 | 3 | OH | 39 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 4.0 | 0.0 | 40.88 | -84.58 | 0.0 | 0.0 | 0.1 | 10 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 161 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

Comment: om,yr,mo,dy,date,time,tz,st,stf,stn,mag,inj,fat,loss,closs,slat,slon,elat,elon,len,wid,ns,sn,sg,f1,f2,f3,f4,fc
1,1950,01,03,1950-01-03,11:00:00,3,MO,29,1,3,3,0,6.0,0.0,38.77,-90.22,38.83,-90.03,9.5,150,2,0,1,0,0,0,0,0
2,1950,01,03,1950-01-03,11:55:00,3,IL,17,2,3,3,0,5.0,0.0,39.1,-89.3,39.12,-89.23,3.6,130,1,1,1,135,0,0,0,0
3,1950,01,03,1950-01-03,16:00:00,3,OH,39,1,1,1,0,4.0,0.0,40.88,-84.58,0.0,0.0,0.1,10,1,1,1,161,0,0,0,0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd try a slightly different approach. I'd use [between](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.between.html#pandas-series-between) and a [timedelta](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Timedelta.html#pandas-timedelta) to simplify the types and the number of conditions needed.

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'om': {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 4, 4: 5},
                   'yr': {0: 1950, 1: 2000, 2: 2005, 3: 2005, 4: 2010},
                   'mo': {0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 1, 4: 7},
                   'dy': {0: 3, 1: 3, 2: 3, 3: 6, 4: 14},
                   'date': {0: '1950-01-03', 1: '2000-01-03',
                            2: '2005-01-03', 3: '2005-01-06',
                            4: '2010-07-14'},
                   'time': {0: '11:00:00', 1: '12:00:00',
                            2: '18:00:00', 3: '20:00:00',
                            4: '15:00:00'},
                   'tz': {0: 3, 1: 3, 2: 3, 3: 3, 4: 3},
                   'st': {0: 'MO', 1: 'IL', 2: 'OH', 3: 'PA', 4: 'NY'}})

new_df = (
    df[
        # Yr between 2000 and 2005 (bounds inclusive)
        df['yr'].between(2000, 2005) &
        # Time Delta between start and end time (bounds inclusive)
        pd.to_timedelta(df['time']).between(pd.Timedelta("12:00:00"),
                                            pd.Timedelta("18:00:00"))]
)

print(new_df)
```

Src (`df`):

```
   om    yr  mo  dy        date      time  tz  st
0   1  1950   1   3  1950-01-03  11:00:00   3  MO
1   2  2000   1   3  2000-01-03  12:00:00   3  IL
2   3  2005   1   3  2005-01-03  18:00:00   3  OH
3   4  2005   1   6  2005-01-06  20:00:00   3  PA
4   5  2010   7  14  2010-07-14  15:00:00   3  NY
```

Output (`new_df`):

```
   om    yr  mo  dy        date      time  tz  st
1   2  2000   1   3  2000-01-03  12:00:00   3  IL
2   3  2005   1   3  2005-01-03  18:00:00   3  OH
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try something like this.

```
tor[
    (tor['year'] > 1999) &
    (tor['year'] < 2006) & 
    (pd.to_datetime(tor['time'], format='%H:%M:%S') >= pd.to_datetime('12:00:00', format='%H:%M:%S')) &
    (pd.to_datetime(tor['time'], format='%H:%M:%S') <= pd.to_datetime('18:00:00', format='%H:%M:%S'))
]
```

Comment: File "main.py", line 10
    cond4 = (pd.to_datetime(tor['time'], format='%H:%M:%S') <= pd.to_datetime('18:00:00', format= '%H:%M:%S')
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Can you try removing conditions 3 and 4 and see if that returns a dataframe?

Comment: You mean just running my first two conditions? Yes that returns a dataframe.

Comment: I've created a mock data set on my end and have been able to get the code I just updated to run. See if that works for you.

Comment: Ok, I think this might work. What do I tell it to print thoug?

Comment: If you're running the code in a Jupyter Notebook, it should just return the filtered dataframe. If you're writing a script you could assign the results to a variable and then print the variable. 

`
x = tor[...]
print(x)
`

Comment: If it works for you, could you accept my comment as the solution? I'm usually the one asking for help on here.

Comment: I set it equal to a variable but it returns a dataframe full of NaN.

Comment: Can you try adjusting some of the parameters in the code? Are you sure there are observations that meet the criteria?

Comment: Yes there are observations that meet the criteria.

Comment: Well @ChiliDog I'm out of ideas. I wanted to help you and get my first solution. I wish you luck on getting this figured out.